# How to enable workspace files in Jenkins when running an ECS task as agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a Jenkins instance deployed on ECS Fargate which uses a docker image for its tasks/agents when jobs are built. I need to be able to see some of the files associated with the jobs in the workspace after the builds finish, however, Im noticing that when I click on "Workspaces" in Jenkins that the path is not active and I can't click on the location to access the files.

Is there a way to enable this for each task that runs in Jenkins so that I can click the workspace link to view the files?

I've tried googling a bit about this ,but havent really found anything specific to the use case for jenkins deployed on fargate.

Comment: 'the path is not active ' - can you share a screenshot please? what does that look like? what is your Jenkins `Workspace Root Directory` set to (Jenkins > Configuration)? and what version of Jenkins? Jenkins is a beast that changes every version 

Comment: Yes that's part of the pain :). So basically if I click on the specific build for the Jenkins job, then open "Workspaces", all I see is /home/jenkins/workspaces/build-ami on fargate-cloud-847394 (this last bit is the ecs task being spun up), but I can't click on the workspaces path to access the files. It's just a inactive path. Home directory is /var/jenkins in Manage > System. Maybe some way to set this in ecs, idk?